# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null (console error)

Tags: javascript, parallax

I attempting to create a basic parallax background, the code works, but I have this console error that I can't get rid off.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Here is a link to a codepenn for a working example:

https://codepen.io/bruno-gomes/pen/rXqOaK?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div class="hero" id="parallax-1"></div>
<div class="content"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 60px 0 70px;
  background-image: url("http://piersrueb.com/sample/sample-3.jpg");
}

.content {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {

   const parallax = (id, modifier) => {
   const paraId = document.querySelector(id);

       paraId.setAttribute('style', 'background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; transition-property: background-position;');

       const sp = () => {
           const x = paraId.getBoundingClientRect().top / modifier;
           const y = Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
           paraId.style.backgroundPosition = `center ${  y  }px`;
       };
       sp();
       window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
           sp();
       });
   };

   parallax("#parallax-1", 8);
};
```

I'm really just trying to find a way to clear that console error.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips on how to approach this.

Comment: Seems to work fine in the pen...what's your browser?

Comment: I've tested in chrome and it seems to work fine, what browser are you using?

Comment: so in your code it can not find the element so you need figure out why it can not find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: paraId && paraId.setAttribute...

```
window.onload = function() {

   const parallax = (id, modifier) => {
   const paraId = document.querySelector(id);

       paraId && paraId.setAttribute('style', 'background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; transition-property: background-position;');

       const sp = () => {
           const x = paraId.getBoundingClientRect().top / modifier;
           const y = Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
           paraId.style.backgroundPosition = `center ${  y  }px`;
       };
       sp();
       window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
           sp();
       });
   };

   parallax("#parallax-1", 8);
};
```